# Kotlin dependency not behaving like Kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a Kotlin dependency that I wrote and am now trying to use it in a separate project. When I add it to the other project variables declared like `val hits = 0` can not be referenced by using the variable `hits` but by using `getHits()` which would make sense if I was using java in the second project but I am not. In other Kotlin projects I have worked on in the past this was not an issue and the only thing that I can think of that is different in the build is that I have set `transitive = false` on the gradle dependency because that was causing another issue. Anyway I am confused on what this would be caused by and appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Intellij decompiler is was considering a class that I know was written in Kotlin a java class so I tried to change some things. The problem was one of two things:

1. I was using the maven plugin for gradle.
2. I had both a `compileKotlin` and a `compileJava` when I was only using Kotlin.

I belive that the problem was caused by the former because I have used both `compileKotlin` and `compileJava` fine together before but I had never used the maven plugin but I added it because something else was complaining that it needed it.